# Using TwythonStreamer to stream a specific user

Tags: python, twitter, twython

I'm trying to use Twython to tweet at a specific user when they tweet.  I can't seem to figure out how to only stream the users tweets.

I've tried:

```
stream = MyStreamer(APP_KEY, APP_SECRET, OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET)
stream.statuses.filter(follow=['25073877'])
```

The stream returned tweets mentioning the user, possibly as well as the user's own tweets.

I can't find the answer anywhere so if someone could help that'd be great.  Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do this automatically. You'll have to filter the tweets you get and select the ones originated by the user you're interested in. Good luck.

Comment: @lrnzcig yeah I was able to do it that way, filtering data['user']['screen_name']. It's unfortunate it can't do it from the stream initially because it would only be dealing with 2 or 3 tweets a day instead of thousands. Thanks for replying.

Comment: Out of interest, what are you intending on tweeting at Donald Trump? https://twitter.com/intent/user?user_id=25073877

Comment: If you like the guy my answer is words of encouragement. If you loathe him my answer is horrible things. 

Comment: Justin, I think I'm trying to accomplish the same thing. But maybe I don't have the code quite right?

    stream.statuses.filter(follow='759251', tweet_mode='extended')